# casting a string as a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url, casting

In JavaScript, I can <s>cast</s> convert numbers to strings and vice versa, but there is no way to <s>cast</s> convert a string to an object

```
num = 1
str = '1'

num_as_str = String(num) // "1"
str_as_num = Number(str) // 1

str = '{ a: "foo", b: "bar", c: { a: "foo", b: "bar" }}'
str_as_obj = Object(str) // does not exist
```

Assuming my string (to be <s>cast</s> converted as an object) is predictable and relatively simply, what is the best way to achieve the above other than using a `regexp` to parse out the indiv key-val pairs? Suggestions welcome

**background:** I want to do the above because I want to be able to pass and receive complex values in a URL. For example, `/index.html?q=within({r:20, u: "kms", lat: 35.32, lng: -22.0132})` (of course, I will `URL encode/decode` properly along the way). Fwiw, the node `querystring` module wipes out anything other strings, numbers, booleans and arrays by coercing them to empty strings.

**background2:** of course, I know about `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, but I have a user-submitted URL querystring param that is most easily transmitted as an object, except a querystring cannot deal with an object. That is what I am trying to find a way around.

Comment: That's why there's [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html): _"JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is an open standard file format and data interchange format that uses human-readable text to store and transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and arrays (or other serializable values)"_ (`JSON.stringify()`,  `JSON.parse()`)

Comment: "Casting a string to an object" generally makes no sense. If you have a *JSON representation* of an object, `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: I don't have a JSON rep of an obj. I have a str that looks like an object, and would be an object if it were declared as such from the get go. What I have is a URL param that makes sense as an obj but can only be transferred as a string

Comment: Then you'll need to `eval()` it, which is usually a bad idea. Why can't you use JSON, a *textual data interchange format* designed for this exact purpose?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, makes sense :)

Comment: @deceze a user will submit a URL such as `/index.html?q=within({r:20, u: "kms", lat: 35.32, lng: -22.0132})`. When and where can I intercept that and stringify it other than on the server with the `querystring` module? But, as I said, `querystring` coerces everything other than a number, string, or boolean to an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do the above because I want to be able to pass and receive complex values in a URL

Use JSON, not a JavaScript object initializer.

> of course, I know about JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, but I have a user-submitted URL querystring param that is most easily transmitted as an object

The JSON version (`{"a":"foo","b":"bar","c":{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}}`) is just as easily transmitted. It URI-encodes to

```
 %7B%22a%22%3A%22foo%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22bar%22%2C%22c%22%3A%7B%22a%22%3A%22foo%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22bar%22%7D%7D
```

vs. your original:

```
%7Ba%3A%22foo%22%2Cb%3A%22bar%22%2Cc%3A%7Ba%3A%22foo%22%2Cb%3A%22bar%22%7D%7D
```

Not much difference. (Yes, it's slightly longer.) And it has the advantage that `JSON.parse` is a built-in feature that doesn't allow arbitrary code execution.

---

If you **must** use the object literal string instead, you have to *parse* that string. There are two built-in ways to do it (`eval` and `new Function`), but unfortunately both of them *execute* the code, and don't limit what the code can be — you can't say, for instance, "only allow an object literal and no function calls."

It sounds like it's entirely possible that User A will be specifying the string and then you'll be evaluating it when showing a page to User B. If so, you can't use `eval` or `new Function` without exposing User B to risks from malicious code.

So you'll need to use a parser like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) or similar instead. You could probably also adapt Crockford's original [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to allow unquoted property names.

So really, JSON is the way to go, but if you really don't want JSON, use a parser that doesn't allow arbitrary code execution.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder seems I will have to figure out how to parse the string (time to up my regexp skills). I can’t use the JSON version because this is for an API I am building and I want the user to be able to submit a “normal” query string param instead of having to worry about a JSON.stringify-ing it first

Comment: @punkish - `{ a: "foo", b: "bar", c: { a: "foo", b: "bar" }}` really isn't a normal query string parameter. :-) `a=foo&b=foo&c[a]=foo&c[b]=bar` would be a fairly normal query string version of that object structure. But here's an idea for you: Provide a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that creates the query string, including doing the necessary URI-encoding. So they type `{ a: "foo", b: "bar", c: { a: "foo", b: "bar" }}` into your bookmarklet, you do `eval("(" + input + ")")` on it (since that's in *their* session), stringify and URI-encode, and give them the URL.

Comment: Whatever you do, though, good luck with it! Hope it goes well.

Comment: Can’t use a bookmarklet or any other user-side interface. It is for an API and it can be specified in any kind of program (html app, R, node, even `curl`). I *have* to either parse it myself or figure out an alternative syntax as you suggest above. It’s just that my original syntax, while not workable, seems the most intuitive to me. That is why I was hoping to pound a square peg in a round hole :)